# How to get Values of one JSON object into the Values of another with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have the following JSON objects:

```
payload4 = '''{
    "Values": [
        {
            "Name": "projectionLength",
            "Attribute": "Test"
        },
        {
            "Name": "projectionHeight",
            "Attribute": "Test"
        }

    ]
}'''


payload5 = '''{
    "Values": [
        {
            "Name": "projectionLength",
            "Attribute": "Test5"
        },
        {
            "Name": "projectionHeight",
            "Attribute": "Test6"
        }

    ]
}'''
```

I need to get the Values of payload5 added to the Values of payload4 but if I use the .update() method payload5 values just overwrite the values of payload4.  What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to unpack the JSON objects, add them together(see code), and then *put them back into a new JSON object*.
Code:

```py
import json
d4=json.loads(payload4)
d5=json.loads(payload5)
d4["Values"].extend(d5["Values"])
newpayload=json.dumps(d4)
```

Output:

```
>>> print(newpayload)
{"Values": [{"Name": "projectionLength", "Attribute": "Test"}, {"Name": "projectionHeight", "Attribute": "Test"}, {"Name": "projectionLength", "Attribute": "Test5"}, {"Name": "projectionHeight", "Attribute": "Test6"}]}
```

Nicer looking version just to give you a feel of whats stored in newpayload(this is *not* the real JSON text):

```
>>> import pprint
>>> pprint.pprint(d4)
{'Values': [{'Attribute': 'Test', 'Name': 'projectionLength'},
            {'Attribute': 'Test', 'Name': 'projectionHeight'},
            {'Attribute': 'Test5', 'Name': 'projectionLength'},
            {'Attribute': 'Test6', 'Name': 'projectionHeight'}]}
```

Comment: When I try and run this code I get a JSONDecodeError Expecting value: line 3 column 41 (char 74) when it does the d4=json.loads.  How can I fix that?

Comment: It's weird because I ran the code again on my laptop with no error,maybe you used a different `payload4`,if so,please upload it so I can take a closer look,thx.

Comment: Thanks @xkcdjerry!  I figured it out.  Your example was awesome!  Thanks again!

Comment: You're welcome :)